# Filtering a field in pivot table and fetching the visible values

Tags: excel, vba

Consider i have a data like this

```
Company     Department  Size
=================================
HCL         BFS         50
HCL         Insurance   60
CTS         BFS         20
CTS         Insurance   30
CTS         Healthcare  50
```

[image: Pivot without any filter]

Here, say i want to filter out BFS and find the total of remaining at each company level as shown below

Case 1: [image: Pivot With filter - after removing BFS as the department using filter]

```
 Company    Department  Total
 CTS    Healthcare  50
        Insurance   30
 CTS Total           80
 HCL    Insurance   60
 HCL Total           60
 Grand Total        140
```

Case 2: [image: Pivot table with only single Company after filtering of the Department]

```
 CTS    Healthcare  50
 CTS Total           50
 Grand Total        50
```

### macro code is tried for the same

```
 For Each V In Set visiblePivot = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2") _
           .PivotFields("Company").VisibleItems
 str = (str & "," & V)
 Next V
 MsgBox str
```

### So what do i get as output, when running the macro?

### EDIT:

for case 1, i get the output as HCL and CTS

```
 ---------------------------
 Microsoft Excel
 ---------------------------
 ,CTS,HCL
 ---------------------------
 OK   
 ---------------------------
```

and for case 2, i get the output as HCL and CTS.

```
 ---------------------------
 Microsoft Excel
 ---------------------------
 ,CTS,HCL
 ---------------------------
 OK   
 ---------------------------
```

### So what do i expect as output?

for case 1, i expect the output as HCL and CTS

```
 ---------------------------
 Microsoft Excel
 ---------------------------
 ,CTS,HCL
 ---------------------------
 OK   
 ---------------------------
```

and for case 2, i expect the output as CTS only.

```
 ---------------------------
 Microsoft Excel
 ---------------------------
 ,CTS
 ---------------------------
 OK   
 ---------------------------
```

### To summarize

Please let me know how to attain using macros the `Company` names that are visible, when the fields in `Department` are filtered

Comment: I just ran this code. It worked great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that i finally used to find the filtered data in a pivot table

```
Sub getVisibleFields()
    ' this will return all the rows that are visible in the 
    'pivot table. Even the subtotal rows
    Set visibleCompany = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2") _
               .PivotFields("Company").DataRange
    For Each V In visibleCompany
        ' different values can be checked to filter out unwanted data
        'to find data like "CTS Total           80"
        If InStrRev(visibleCompany(i + 1), " Total") > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Total is " & visibleCompany(i + 1)
        End If
        str = (str & "," & V)
    Next V
    MsgBox str
 End Sub
```